# specific confirmation email for an event?

Tags: civievent, message-templates

I would like to send an particular email confirmation for certain events.
Is it possible to select a particular model for these events, or must absolutely change the existing model?

Comment: In addition to the answers below I checked if CiviRules has option for Condition = Event Name - but no such luck, not on the version I have anyway.

Comment: Ah that would have been awesome!

Comment: @petednz-fuzion @KarinG-SemperIT regarding CiviRules, you could make the rule trigger on __Participant added/changed__, add a __Field value comparison__, select __Participant__ as entity, __Event__ as field, and use the `event_id` as the value to compare to. That and __Email Api__, allows you to send specific email templates per each event. Happy to add this as an answer if you think is useful.

Comment: nice one andrei - why not add as an answer

Comment: Very Cool @Andrei!

Answer (score 4):

Two options!

Use the text in the Event Config -> Online Registration -> Confirmation Email -> this is Event specific and this text/note will be pasted ahead of the receipt Email - so ahead of what is generated by the message template.

Or - if you want to go into more detail:

You can get into the message-template and add some if logic - that would essentially change the message based on {$event.event_xxx}

Comment: So, I think that the best way is to define specifics events type and update email templates. In that case, I presume that theses changes must be applyied for each civicrm updates.

Comment: Yes... count on that. Message templates will be overridden during upgrade if there are new bits for them - so best to keep copies eg templ.4.7.8 mytempl.4.7.8 and templ.4.7.9 and then run diffs to track edits - and re-apply them.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the fantastic [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) and [E-mail API](https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api)  extensions (developed by CiviCoop), see links for more info.

After installing and enabling both extensions, create a new rule like this:

**Trigger**: Event Participant is added or Event Participant is changed, this will vary depending on your registration workflow, ie if you use the Participant Approval feature

**Condition**: Field value comparison

Comparison criteria:

- Entity: Participant
- Field: Event
- Operator: is equal to (for a    specific event)
- Compare value: 123 (Event Id)

[image]

**Action**: Send e-mail, select your Message template and you're done

If you use the Participant Approval feature you could add a second Field value comparison condition to check for Participant status.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to insert a token of {event.title}, {event.location} etc on the email template triggered by the CiviRule? This would enable to have one rule for a number of events? When I tried it (with {event.title}) it comes up empty (... thank youf registering for      ....). Thx A.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is only one message template for event confirmation following a online registration. So if you change it, it will apply on every event unless you add some smarty code in it.

Another method is to disable the confirmation email for this event and use schedule reminders instead.

- administer -> communication -> schedule reminder
- entity => Activity - Event registration - Completed
- create a schedule reminder that start 0 hour after Activity Date Time
- don't forget to enable cron job : Administer -> System settings -> Schedule Jobs and set `Send Scheduled Reminders` to `every time cron job run`

As it is an automatic process, i recommend to do some tests before activate it widely.

**EDIT** This will not work because you can't specify which event will trigger the reminder.

Comment: Just noticed that you could not restrict the events in the reminder so i guess the answer by @KarinG covers the proper solutions.